# Quisiera poder expresar en radianes?

Tags: java

estoy tratando de contruir un metodo con unas indicaciones pero la parte final pide una indicacion algo ambigua giro una bola al angulo correspondiente y luego "Nótese que el ángulo no podrá superar los 360º. En tal caso, el valor del ángulo sería el módulo de la división por 360."

```
double anguloDeMovimiento;

public double girar(double grado){

    if(grado <= 360){
        anguloDeMovimiento = Math.toRadians(anguloDeMovimiento) + 
        Math.toRadians(grado);
    }else if(grado >= 361){ 
        anguloDeMovimiento = Math.toRadians(anguloDeMovimiento)+Math.toRadians(grado);
    }

    return anguloDeMovimiento;
}
```

Comment: te estan indicando que si el angulo supera los 360º, entonces has superado (al menos) una vuelta completa. debes "recalcular" de nuevo que angulo es (te indican la formula para obtenerlo) y luego despues a ese nuevo angulo le aplicas la formula de conversion de radianes.

Comment: Puedes aplicar el módulo siempre, incluso si el ángulo es menor a 360, con eso te ahorras el `if` para saber si debes aplicarlo o no, aún si fuera menor no te afectaría el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

leyendo al pie de la letra seria simplemente volver a uno si llega a pasar de 360. Creo que eso era lo que no entendia

```
  public double girar(double grado) {
        if (anguloDeMovimiento + grado <= 360) {
            anguloDeMovimiento = anguloDeMovimiento + grado;

        } else if (anguloDeMovimiento + grado >= 361) {

            anguloDeMovimiento = (anguloDeMovimiento + grado) / 360;

        }

        return anguloDeMovimiento;

    }
```